# Remove keytool certificate from Mac

Tags: python, macos, ssl, terminal, keytool

Total newbiew to coding things related to ssl

I am working on `python` on mac, where in i am supposed to make a handshake using cert/key and then xml signing using another pair

During the process,i am frequently getting error as below :

```
"SSLError(1, u'[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA] tlsv1 alert unknown ca (_ssl.c:590)')"
```

I am suspecting this is because of adding the `cacerts` through keytool as below (*i googled it and copy pasted after reading some docs online*)

```
sudo keytool -keystore cacerts -trustcacerts -importcert -alias someCA -file root.CA.crt
```

**Problem :**

I executed the above `keytool` query on multiple places through terminal, so same file got added under multiple aliases, if i need to delete it, i am not able to do so.**How can i delete this keytool certificate along with alias from command line, considering i am not using Java**?

**Terminal Attempts :**

- Adding :

  `` /etc/certs > sudo keytool -keystore cacerts -trustcacerts -importcert
  -alias someCA -file root.CA.crt 
  Enter keystore password: 
  Re-enter new password: 
  . 
  . 
  . 
  . 
  ///some cert details 
  . 
  . 
  . 
  Trust this certificate? [no]:  yes 
  Certificate was added to keystore` ``
- Delete:

  `/etc/certs > keytool -list
  keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: /Users/codebase/.keystore
  /etc/certs > keystore
  -bash: keystore: command not found
  /etc/certs > keytool -list -keystore .keystore
  keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: .keystore
  /etc/certs > keytool -list -keystore .keystore -alias someCA
  keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: .keystore`